# Y value minus 1 in tooltip HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am struggling finding a way to return the previous Y value in the chart on the current Y value's tooltip. The idea is that I want to perform the action of "this.y - this.y(-1)" (getting that this.(y-1)) value and find the difference between the current and the one before that. Ideally, this will be in the tooltip for each of the values in the chart

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 310px"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    $.get("data.csv", function (csv) {
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            title: {
                text: 'Testing HighCharts'
            },
            data: {
                csv: csv
            },
            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter:function(){
                        return '<b>Date:</b> ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%B %e %Y', this.x) + '<br>' + '<b>Amount:</b> ' + this.y + '<br>';
                    }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    marker: {
                       enabled: true,
                       fillColor: 'FFFFFF',
                       radius: 4
                    },
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    color: '#CC0000',
                    width: 3
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>


</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **index** and **series** properties of **this.point** object inside the tooltip **formatter**.

```
tooltip: {
    formatter:function(){
        var diffText = '',
            i = this.point.index;

        if (i > 0) {
            diffText = '<br><b>Difference: </b>' + (this.y - this.point.series.data[i-1].y);
        }

        return '<b>Date:</b> ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%B %e %Y', this.x) + '<br>' + '<b>Amount:</b> ' + this.y + '<br>' + diffText;
    }
},
```

Here is the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/alex_ua/7u80r0c3/2/

Comment: Hi Alex,
That works super amazing in the fiddler example and is indeed what I am looking for. It seems though on my server when I change the code, it errors with the following:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of undefined

It appears that the point is not set :/ Any idea why?

Comment: It can be wrong context (this) or maybe different data or changes in params object cause an error. Or different library versions.

Comment: Thank you! Found the error by debugging the object, the correct path is: `this.points[0].point.index` and `this.points[0].point.series.data[i-1].y`